# checkbox not appear in table data angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular 7 with an angular-material table that data can expand. I'm trying to put a checkbox per row left to the table, but it does not appear:

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-diagram">
          <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{element.description}}

        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element || selection.toggle(row)">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

For reference, the full code you can find here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expandandselect).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your checkbox column is not included in the `columnsToDisplay` array. Add it there and it will show up.

Note: As you are iterating over `columnsToDisplay`, just adding the `'select'` column will throw an error (you are defining it separately in the template already). You would also need to change your table definition to something like this:

**Component**

```
columnsToDisplay = ['select', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position'];
```

**Template**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
  <ng-container *ngIf="column === 'select'; else notSelect">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #notSelect>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

> Check out the edited stackblitz
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expandandselect-q4fmox?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html).